# Can't get text from edittext?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have updated to ADT version 20. After that I can't use EditText. For API level 16 it shows some error. For lower API levels there is no error but I can't get the input of EditText. It shows an empty result.

Sample code I used:

**java code**

```
public class sample extends Activity {
EditText edt;
Button btn;
TextView txt;
String str;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    str = edt.getText().toString();
    btn.setClickable(true);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("WordWeb","entered - "+str);
            txt.setText("you entered"+str);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**XML CODING**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Search"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10pt"
    android:text="Button" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you are trying to get text from `EditText` in `onCreate()` of Activity, which has no any text contains yet.

So Just put the line,  `str = edt.getText().toString();` in button's click() then you will get the result,

Like,,

```
btn.setClickable(true);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        str = edt.getText().toString();
        Log.d("WordWeb","entered - "+str);
        txt.setText("you entered"+str);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your statement `str = edt.getText().toString();` should be inside the `onClick` handler.

Answer (score 2):

The code cannot access the value because after `onCreate` ends the value found in the `EditText` abd `str` is beyond the scope. So put the `str = edt.getText().toString();` statement inside the `onClick` so that when user clicks the button it can access the value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get `EditText` (i.e. edt) value in `onCreate()` and I think you are entering value after the completion of `onCreate()` method.So that means you are not getting value for your `str`.

That's why you are not able to set the value to `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

just put text inside your button otherwise it will not work becz whatever u are getting in strings is also working like u are just cre

Comment: plz dn't uz slanz in SO (Please don't use slangs in SO). [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/20230341)